# Asynchronous REST Web Service?

Tags: rest, service, web, jax-rs

I have to mention that I am new to Web services.  Now, my question is if REST web services (including JAX-RS) provide any means of creating asynchronous web service invocation, or that only SOAP style web services provide asynchronous web services?

Answer (score 0):

By general usage, almost all RESTful transactions are asynchronous to the client, but synchronous on the server. In particular, JavaScript only provides asynchronous methods to make server calls (AJAX, COMET, or WebSockets); but RESTful methods can be called synchronously from other languages, or by using browser navigation (e.g. `form action="POST"` or manipulating the `document.location` or so forth.)

Comment: Asynchronous within the context of Ajax and within the context of web services are 2 different concepts.  Within the context of web services, a web service invocation is asynchronous if the service provides the means of a callback.  Meaning after the server is done, then it somehow (for example by making a callback to a web service on the client's server) informs the client that the task is done.  You are confusing Ajax's concept of asynchronous with web services' concept of asynchronous.

Comment: Ah, you didn't specify. And, in that context, JavaScript is technically incapable of receiving a “real callback,” but any other context of RESTful service invocation could do so. The usual method is something like COMET or polling, however.

Comment: @DanBezdek, do you finnally find the way to implement async REST api with TPL within ServiceStack?